# Alternative for dynamicComponentLoader in angular2 RC5?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am creating an angular2 app in RC5 in which I want to load Components Dynamically.

in RC1 , I did same using dynamicComponentLoader as:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'generic-component',
  templateUrl: 'generic.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['generic.component.css']
})
export class GenericComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('target',{read:ViewContainerRef}) target; 
  @Input('component-name') componentName:string;
  @Input('component-info') componentInfo:string;
  @Input('component-model') componentModel:Object;

  keysRegister:string[]=[     
  'users',
  'employee'
  ]; 
  componentNames:string[]=[      
  'UserComponent',
  'EmpComponent'
  ];

  constructor(private dcl:DynamicComponentLoader) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
      let componentIndex=this.keysRegister.indexOf(this.componentName);
      this.dcl.loadNextToLocation(StandardLib[this.componentNames[componentIndex]],this.target)
    .then(ref=>{
        ref.instance.componentModel=this.componentModel;
    });
    console.log("GenericComponent...... "+this.componentName+" Loaded");

  }

}
```

and whenever I want to load the component I would do:

```
<div *ngIf="columnModel" style="border:1px solid orange">
    <generic-component 
        [component-name]="columnModel.componentName" <!-- I will pass *users* here -->
        [component-model]="columnModel.componentModel"
        [component-info]="columnModel.componentInfo"
    ></generic-component>
</div>
```

I tried using componentResolver but I am not able to get it work correctly.
Any Inputs?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In `RC5` you need to use the `compileComponentAsync()` method from the `Compiler`.

Here is a quick example:

```
constructor(private _comp: Compiler) {}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this._comp.compileComponentAsync(this.componentModel).then(a => this.target.createComponent(a));
}
```

And here is a complete example from a library of mines:

https://github.com/flauc/ng2-simple-components/blob/master/src/modal/modal.component.ts